# FireHose (S3) from CCC

Tags: algorithm

This grade 11 problem has been bothering me since 2010 and I still can't figure out/find a solution even after university.

> Problem Description
>
> There is a very unusual street in your neighbourhood. This street
>   forms a perfect circle, and the circumference of the circle is
>   1,000,000. There are H (1 ≤ H ≤ 1000) houses on the street. The
>   address of each house is the clockwise arc-length from the
>   northern-most point of the circle. The address of the house at the
>   northern-most point of the circle is 0. You also have special ﬁrehoses
>   which follow the curve of the street. However, you wish to keep the
>   length of the longest hose you require to a minimum. Your task is to
>   place k (1 ≤ k ≤ 1000) ﬁre hydrants on this street so that the maximum
>   length of hose required to connect a house to a ﬁre hydrant is as
>   small as possible.
>
> Input Speciﬁcation
>
> The ﬁrst line of input will be an integer H, the number of houses. The
>   next H lines each contain one integer, which is the address of that
>   particular house, and each house address is at least 0 and less than
>   1,000,000. On the H + 2nd line is the number k, which is the number of
>   ﬁre hydrants that can be placed around the circle. Note that a ﬁre
>   hydrant can be placed at the same position as a house. You may assume
>   that no two houses are at the same address. Note: at least 40% of the
>   marks for this question have H ≤ 10.
>
> Output Speciﬁcation
>   On one line, output the length of hose required
>   so that every house can connect to its nearest ﬁre hydrant with that
>   length of hose.
>
> Sample Input
>   4
>   0
>   67000
>   68000
>   77000
>   2
>
> Output for Sample Input
>    5000

[Link to original question](http://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2010/stage1/seniorEn.pdf)

I can't even come up with a brutal force algorithm since the placement might be float number. For example if the houses are located in 1 and 2, then the hydro should be placed at 1.5 and the distance would be 0.5

Comment: It sounds like you could have the same number of hydrants and houses, meaning you could have a hydrant per each house, or am I missing something?

Comment: @monistic you are given the number of houses and the number of hydrant. For example you are given 3 houses located at 1, 2, and 3. And you have only one hydrant to place. Find the minimum distance of the longest hose. (which is going to be 1)

Comment: @mnistic Yes, if `k` >= `H` then the answer is 0, since you can put a hydrant at every house.

Comment: @Steve The goal is to create `k` contiguous groups of houses, where the hydrant is at the midpoint between the first and last house in the group. With `H` houses on a circle, there are `H` points that can act as a boundary between groups. So the brute force approach is to choose `k` of `H` possible dividing points and then compute the distances. A better approach is known as [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). BTW, I can't imagine that many 11th graders would be able to do this problem without a lot of coaching.

Comment: @user3386109 If the houses are evenly spaced it isn't so hard.  I could have solved that version in grade 11.

Comment: @btilly Good point, but then it's more of a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: @user3386109 That is true.  However even if the lengths vary, it is still a polynomial time problem.

Comment: added the sample in/output from the original question for clarity

Comment: @Steve That makes it much clearer.  I just gave you an outline of a strategy that will work.

Comment: The Output for SampleInput is 5000 I suppose, not 500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is quick outline of an answer.

First write a function that can figures out whether you can cover all of the houses with a given maximum length per hydrant.  (The maximum hose will be half that length.)  It just starts at a house, covers all of the houses it can, jumps to the next, and ditto, and sees whether you stretch.  If you fail it tries starting at the next house instead until it has gone around the circle.  This will be a `O(n^2)` function.

Second create a sorted list of the pairwise distances between houses.  (You have to consider it going both ways around for a single hydrant, you can only worry about the shorter way if you have 2+ hydrants.)  The length covered by a hydrant will be one of those.  This takes `O(n^2 log(n))`.

Now do a binary search to find the shortest length that can cover all of the houses.  This will require `O(log(n))` calls to the `O(n^2)` function that you wrote in the first step.

The end result is a `O(n^2 log(n))` algorithm.

And here is working code for all but the parsing logic.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

def _find_hoses_needed (circle_length, hose_span, houses):
    # We assume that houses is sorted.
    answers = [] # We can always get away with one hydrant per house.
    for start in range(len(houses)):
        needed = 1
        last_begin = start
        current_house = start + 1 if start + 1 < len(houses) else 0
        while current_house != start:
            pos_begin = houses[last_begin]
            pos_end = houses[current_house]
            length = pos_end - pos_begin if pos_begin <= pos_end else circle_length + pos_begin - pos_end
            if hose_span < length:
                # We need a new hose.
                needed = needed + 1
                last_begin = current_house
            current_house = current_house + 1
            if len(houses) <= current_house:
                # We looped around the circle.
                current_house = 0
        answers.append(needed)
    return min(answers)

def find_min_hose_coverage (circle_length, hydrant_count, houses):
    houses = sorted(houses)

    # First we find all of the possible answers.
    is_length = set()
    for i in range(len(houses)):
        for j in range(i, len(houses)):
            is_length.add(houses[j] - houses[i])
            is_length.add(houses[i] - houses[j] + circle_length)
    possible_answers = sorted(is_length)

    # Now we do a binary search.
    lower = 0
    upper = len(possible_answers) - 1
    while lower < upper:
        mid = (lower + upper) / 2 # Note, we lose the fraction here.
        if hydrant_count < _find_hoses_needed(circle_length, possible_answers[mid], houses):
            # We need a strictly longer coverage to make it.
            lower = mid + 1
        else:
            # Longer is not needed
            upper = mid
    return possible_answers[lower]

print(find_min_hose_coverage(1000000, 2, [0, 67000, 68000, 77000])/2.0)
```

Comment: does this assume the length of each hose is an int?

Comment: @Steve Nope.  You can even let the addresses of houses be floats and it will work.

Comment: having some trouble following the second part. Mind give a run thru example for the algorithm?

Comment: Great solution. To justify why that first step works: any solution that involves a hydrant position that doesn't have the hose perfectly reach a house and not extend past it could be modified into one that does by shifting the hydrant so that one of the two overhangs now perfectly covers a house.

Comment: @Steve I provided a Python implementation of the algorithm.  Feel free to vary parameters, add print statements, etc.

Comment: beautiful answer. Thanks!